# Why is the targe count different from expected?

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

The following is my code, i intend to calculate how many times a list is modified, but the count seems to be wrong, my code is shown below:

```
t=(0,999999,"state")

cachLine = []

for x in range(0,2):
    cachLine.append(t);

cache = []
for x in range(0,1):
    cache.append(cachLine)

cacheList = []

for x in range(0,8):
    cacheList.append(cache)

count=0

for cacheI,cache in enumerate(cacheList):
    for clI,cl in enumerate(cache):
        for bI,(valid, address, state) in enumerate(cl):

            if state =='state': 
                cacheList[cacheI][clI][bI] = (valid, address,'invalid')
                count +=1
print(count)
```

The count is 2 in this case, which is not as expected, it should be 16

However, if i change the order of the count+=1 to

```
for cacheI,cache in enumerate(cacheList):
    for clI,cl in enumerate(cache):
        for bI,(valid, address, state) in enumerate(cl):
            count +=1    
            if state =='state': 
                cacheList[cacheI][clI][bI] = (valid, address,'invalid')

print(count)
```

I get the correct count of 16. In any of the two case, i get an output of cacheList:

```
[[[(0, 999999, 'invalid'), (0, 999999, 'invalid')]], [[(0, 999999, 'invalid'), (0, 999999, 'invalid')]], [[(0, 999999, 'invalid'), (0, 999999, 'invalid')]], [[(0, 999999, 'invalid'), (0, 999999, 'invalid')]], [[(0, 999999, 'invalid'), (0, 999999, 'invalid')]], [[(0, 999999, 'invalid'), (0, 999999, 'invalid')]], [[(0, 999999, 'invalid'), (0, 999999, 'invalid')]], [[(0, 999999, 'invalid'), (0, 999999, 'invalid')]]]
```

which is 16 of tuples (0, 999999, 'invalid').

What is wrong with count in the first code?

Answer (score 1):

You should copy your lists before appending them:

```
import copy

cache = []
for x in range(0,1):
    cache.append(copy.deepcopy(cachLine))

cacheList = []

for x in range(0,8):
    cacheList.append(copy.deepcopy(cache))
```

Answer (score 0):

Curious...

If you change "state" to anything else, for example State, foo or xyzzy, it works and you don't get the "invalid" fields in cacheList.

It appears "state" is a keyword or named parameter somewhere inside enumerate and something gets broken.  Not sure if this helps at all.

Hannu

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you append 8 time the SAME cache, containing the SAME cacheline. Your cacheList ultimately contains a bunch of reference to the exact same objet: a list of two tuples

So the first time you call `cacheList[cacheI][clI][bI] = (valid, address,'invalid')`, you modify this common object. count = 1 and each cacheline is now:

```
[(0,999999,"state"), (0,999999,"invalid")]
```

After the second time, count = 2 and cacheline is:

```
[(0,999999,"invalid"), (0,999999,"invalid")]
```

After the first completion of your innerloop, every "state" has turned into "invalid". Therefore, your count stops at 2.

The solution is indeed to use the `copy` module, as it will create new objects, instead of just passing a reference.